# Is servicestack MVC powerpack compatible with ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I am currently using the servicestack powerpack (ServiceStackController) in an ASP.NET MVC 3 project but I am now considering upgrading to VS2012, .NET 4.5 and ASP.NET MVC 4. Has anybody tested whether the powerpack works with ASP.NET MVC 4?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have tested it myself now and it seems to work fine.